# How do I structure MVVM with Collections?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm having trouble understanding how to apply the MVVM pattern when Lists/Collections are involved.

Say the `MainModel` has a few properties and methods, as well as a list that contains other `DetailModel` objects. The `DetailModel` objects can be added, removed, or re-ordered.

The `MainView` will show a few controls related the the root model, and have a `ListBox` populated from the list. Each item will have it's own sub-view via a `DetailModelView` `UserControl`.

Finally, there is a `MainViewModel`. This has properties backed by the `MainModel`'s properties and methods, bound to the Main View, with change notification keeping everything in sync. (Up to this point, I am comfortable with the pattern - more stating this in case there is something fundamental I am missing...)

When it comes to handling the list, I get confused.  I have come across several examples where the `MainViewModel` simply exposes the list of `DetailModels` to the view, and the `DetailModelViews` are bound directly to the models.  This *functions*, but is problematic.  It does not consistently following the pattern (no `DetailViewModel` exists), and it drives me to include some UI-related code in my detail models.  It seems clear to me that the `MainViewModel` should expose a list of `DetailViewModels` for the UI to bind, but I am stuck on how to implement such a thing!

How should manage the two lists (`DetailModels` and `DetailViewModels`)?  I am really confused as where I initially populate the `DetailViewModel` list, and how I should handle adding, removing, or changing the order of the items to keep them synchronized!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually `Models` are nothing more than data objects. They shouldn't contain any code to do things like add/remove items from a list. This is the `ViewModel's` job.

In your case, I would create a `MainViewModel` that has the following properties:

- `ObservableCollection<DetailViewModel> Details`
- `ICommand AddDetailCommand`
- `ICommand RemoveDetailCommand`

If your `MainModel` class is a data object, you can either expose it, or it's properties from the `MainViewModel` as well. Exposing it's Properties is the "MVVM purist" approach, while exposing the entire Model is sometimes more practical.

Your `MainViewModel` is in charge of creating the initial list of `DetailViewModels`, and it is in charge of Adding/Removing these items as well. For example, in the `PropertyChanged` event for the `MainViewModel.MainModel` property, it might rebuild the `MainViewModel.Details` collection, and the `CollectionChanged` event for the `MainViewModel.Details` property would update `MainViewModel.MainModel.Details`

Comment: This pretty much describes the end solution pretty concisely.  My "MainViewModel" also has commands to move the selected item up or down in the list...

Answer (score 6):

You are right to have a separate `DetailModels` list and `DetailViewModels` list.  The DetailViewModels list should be a property of type `ObservableCollection<DetailViewModel>`.  You can populate the observable list when you set the Model (or at construction time, if you pass the model into the constructor of your ViewModel.)

```
private ObservableCollection<DetailViewModel> m_details;
public IEnumerable<DetailViewModel> Details
{
   get { return m_details; }
}
```

You can the subscribe to m_details.[CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx).  This is where you can handle re-ordering the contents of the list in the Model.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the only time you get away with exposing model objects to the view is if you're doing simple read-only presentation, e.g. displaying a string property in a `ComboBox`.  If there's any kind of actual UI involving the object (especially one involving two-way data binding), a view model is needed.

Typically, a master VM's constructor will look like this:

```
public MasterViewModel(MasterModel m)
{
   _Model = m;
   _Detail = new ObservableCollection<DetailViewModel>(m.Detail);
}
```

where `MasterModel.Detail` is a collection of `DetailModel` objects, and `_Detail` is a backing field for a `Detail` property that's exposed to the view.

As far as adding, removing, and reordering items in this list is concerned, in the UI at least this will be done through commands on the `MasterViewModel`, which must manipulate both `MasterModel.Detail` and `MasterViewModel.Detail`.  That's a bit of a pain, but unless you want to repopulate `MasterViewModel.Detail` after every change to `MasterModel.Detail`, it's really unavoidable.

On the other hand, if you've been wondering "why would I ever need to write unit tests for view models?", now you know.

Comment: I'm still working out my solution, but I wanted to point out a big helper in here: "repopulate MasterViewModel.Detail after every change to MasterModel.Detail"  Oddly, that thought hadn't occurred to me!  I certainly have to build it once upon initialization, so I can rebuild at any time.

Comment: I am wondering whether `new ObservableCollection<DetailViewModel>(m.Detail);` will work since `m.Detail` is of a different type than the type specified as `<DetailViewModel>` through the ObservableCollection generic. _I doubt that it will work_.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that I think addresses this issue very nicely using an `ObservableViewModelCollection<TViewModel, TModel>`

It's nice and lazy.  It takes an ObservableCollection and a ViewModelFactory in the ctor.  I  like it because it keeps state at the model layer where it belongs.  User operations on the GUI can invoke commands at the VM which manipulate the M via public methods on the M.  Any resulting changes at the M layer will be automatically handled by the class in this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/2177659/456490

Note my comment regarding SL vs. WPF