# Pre-initialization object in a List<object>

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to ask you this issue which block me for a long time

I have a list like

```
 List<ViewModel> listVoie = new List<ViewModel>();
```

and in this list the object "ViewModel" is a kind of line draw function, everytime i need to give it two points 4example

```
 Dictionary<int, double> pointAdd= new Dictionary<int, double>();     
 pointAdd.Add(listPoint1[i], 0);
 pointAdd.Add(listPoint2[i], -500);
```

As you can see I have another two list to store int

```
List<int> listPoint1 = new List<int>; List<int> listPoint2 = new List<int>;
```

the length of these two lists is equal but the real value is uncertain ; 
I need to define every line as a new object "ViewModel" how could I do this ? from now on I have this imy mind ; but it cannot work since ViewModel v will return a NullReferenceException

```
List<ViewModel> listVoie = new List<ViewModel>(new ViewModel[listPoint1.Count]);
foreach (ViewModel v in listVoie)
{
    Dictionary<int, double> pointAdd= new Dictionary<int, double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listPoint1.Count; i++)
    {
        pointAdd.Add(listPoint1[i], 0);
        pointAdd.Add(listPoint2[i], -500);
        v.point= pointAdd;
        ....
        i++;
    }
```

Can someone help me with this ? May forgive my stupid question bother you ... thanks

the two Lists listPoint1 and listPoint2 are not empty ; they load some values from other method.

Comment: Where do you add some values in listPoint1 and listPoint2?

Comment: Both `listPoint1` and `listPoint2` are empty in your code

Comment: In the other methods , it will return a list of value in listPoint1 and listPoint2 , by using breakPoint ; I could see it does pass the value there;

Comment: Check out this post too, it's not an answer to your question, but it is related and I think interesting nevertheless: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256793/mvvm-sync-collections

Comment: @FANWicked can you specify your goal? You want to create `Dictionary<int, double>` which will have all items from both lists? Then why you have `listVoie`?

Comment: @Sergey In fact I would like to return a List<ViewModel>with each ViewModel has their own two values one from listPoint1, one from listPoint2

Comment: @FANWicked how ViewModel looks like? I.e. what values of model should be initialized with data from `listPoint1` and `listPoint2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line:

```
List<ViewModel> listVoie = new List<ViewModel>(new ViewModel[listPoint1.Count]);
```

actually creates an **empty List**. The parameter you have **doesn't indicate you fill the list with N objects**, it's just here for performances purposes (internal implementation of `List<T>`: initializes the array that'll contains your list items with the right size).

What you should do is:

```
// Empty list for now
List<ViewModel> listVoie = new List<ViewModel>();

foreach (int j = 0; j < listPoint1.Count; j++)
{
    // Creates the ViewModel here, and adds it to the list
    var myViewModel = new myViewModel();
    listVoie.Add(myViewModel);

    Dictionary<int, double> pointAdd= new Dictionary<int, double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listPoint1.Count; i++)
    {
        pointAdd.Add(listPoint1[i], 0);
        pointAdd.Add(listPoint2[i], -500);
        myViewModel.point= pointAdd;
        ....
        i++;
    }
```

Same for other lists you have.

Comment: Thnaks ! it's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

> In fact I would like to return a `List<ViewModel>` with each `ViewModel`
>   has their own two values one from `listPoint1`, one from `listPoint2`

You can simply [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) both sequences:

```
List<ViewModel> listVoie = 
    listPoint1.Zip(listPoint2, (p1,p2) => new ViewModel {
          // use p1 and p2
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your ViewModel as follows:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<int, double> point;

    public void SetPoints(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
    {
        point = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            point.Add(list1[i], 0);
            point.Add(list2[i], -500);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

create a new class for List as follows:

```
public class ViewModelList : List<ViewModel>
{
    public void UpdateAllPoints(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
    {
        this.Clear();
        foreach (var item in list1)
        {
            var viewModel = new ViewModel();
            viewModel.SetPoints(list1, list2);
            this.Add(viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
        var listVoie = new ViewModelList();
        listVoie.UpdateAllPoints(listPoint1, listPoint2);
```